# Sound recognition or matching

Tags: python, audio-recording, audio

I want to compare sounds to another sound to find matches. Lets say I have a sound if a beetle (bug) or a car driving on tar etc. now if i play the application this sound it should be able to find a match based on that if any.

I have never worked with these kinds of things so i would appreciate any ideas or background in this subject.

I would be using python for this purpous.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is no small feat... but this is how I would start.

1) Use a DFT to break down the Sound 1 into its Fourier components

2) Normalize the DFT to control for volume differences

3) Use a scanning window to DFT Sound 2, again normalizing

4) Calculate a least squares error between the two and a threshold to trigger a match notification (or a Hidden Markov Model if you want to get fancy)

If that makes zero sense to you, I suggest you start here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_Analysis

Once those make some sense, go find yourself a Intro to Signal Processing textbook.

Comment: Thanks, I will be reading allot :-)